# Regex to match entire line starting with non numeric word

Tags: regex

I'm working on certain data, and want to sort out them using regex. My requirement is that I want to match every line starting with a non numeric word. I'm tried using.

`/^[^\d\s]+\b.*/gm`

However the above regex doesn't match lines like -

"12#22 why is it so"

Regex considers 12#22 as a numeric word but 12#22 is a non numeric word. Can anyone explain the proper solution for my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/^[^\d\s]+\b.*/gm` matches any line that starts with one or more characters other than digits and whitespaces followed with a word boundary. `12#22 why is it so` starts with a digit, so it is not a match.

You need

```js
/^(?!\d+[^\S\n\r]).*/gm
```

*Details*:

- `^` - start of  a line
- `(?!\d+[^\S\n\r])` - immediately to the right of the current location, there should be no one or more digits and then a horizontal whitespace
- `.*` - rest of the line.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uXfWBR/2).